# The spread of cable tv

Tags: data-request, usa, media

Is there a data set that shows the date of the first availability of cable tv or (not necessarily the same data) the date of first public broadcasting in each state or city in the United States?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a few, certainly not all, dates in this pdf about the history of television. one example: Cable television is introduced in Pennsylvania as a means of bringing television to rural areas. (1948)

not a complete answer, but some information in here for you:
http://tarlton.law.utexas.edu/exhibits/mason_&_associates/documents/timeline.pdf